# Closing vs status-completed

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

Why was this question closed: [Who should the beta moderators be?](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/203/31)?
It is a perfectly valid question. Indeed, it was important for selecting the beta moderators. Why isn't it simply tagged with [status-completed](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-completed)?

Closing a question suggests that it was off-topic, poorly phrased and never fixed, unwelcome, etc, whereas [status-completed](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-completed) would more accurately reflect the status of the question.

Answer (score 1):

That's what's usually done with these threads on meta sites that have a limited lifetime: close them, since there's no point in answering them any more, but leave them around because they reflect a point in the site's history. The close reason is “too localized”: it's not a bad question per se, but it is no longer relevant.

Comment: You could also lock them: e.g, http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/67/who-should-the-moderators-be

Comment: How about leaving it closed and adding tag [tag:status-completed].